# In a drap and drop between explorer and your app, how to know your app directory?

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I have a little command line app tool `xyz.exe` that accepts a filename `f` as argument and then will call a program `abc.exe` that lives in the same folder as `xyz.exe` with some data as argument plus `f`.

The ideia would be to drag and drop some file from windows explorer into my program so it calls `abc.exe` with the proper parameters. When I say to drop into my program, I mean to drop the file into `abc.exe`, so it runs it with the filename as argument.

The problem is that I need a way to know in which folder abc.exe is. I know it will be the same folder as `xyz.exe`, but it seems that in drag and drop operations `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will show up some windows folder instead of the folder where `abc.exe`/`xyz.exe` reside.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

to find the current directory.